# Quotes and double quotes in SQL command with PHP

Tags: php

I found a piece of code like this:

```
<?php
  class myClass {
      function myFunc(&$par1) {
          // [...]
          $val2 = $par1->field1;
          // [...]
          $val3_escaped = mysql_real_escape_string($someVar2);
          $cmdInsert = "insert into tab1(col1,col2,col3, col4) values(1,'$val2',\"$val3_escaped\",'val4')";
          $result = mysql_query($cmdInsert, $myConnection);
    }
  }
?>
```

I'm wondering what is the difference between `'$val2'` and `\"$val3_escaped\"`? Are both valid?
I guess that should be correct only with single quote, but it seems to works fine only with `\"`.
What's the right sintax?

Thanks.

Comment: Use prepared statements. Please protect yourself against SQL injection. Then you don't even need to worry about quotes vs double quotes.

Comment: The right syntax would be to bin all of it, stop using the defunct `mysql_` extension and move to `mysqli_` or `pdo` prepared statements with bound parameters...

Comment: It's a very old existing CRM, I'm a Java programmer and I'm trying to fix a little bug on that application. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The escape character is for the benefit of PHP (since the PHP string is delimited by " characters). It has nothing to do with what is sent to MySQL.

Single quotes delimit strings in SQL.

Double quotes have no meaning in standard SQL. In MySQL they can mean the same as ' or ` depending on the [ANSI_QUOTES setting](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes). Avoid them.

---

**Warning**:  You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) which has been **removed** entirely from the latest version of PHP. You should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

With a modern replacement you could use prepared statements with placeholders instead of worrying about quoting variables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's a very old existing CRM, I'm a Java programmer and I'm trying to fix a little bug on that application. Just one question... php substitutes any variable that start with $ inside a string? You don't need to close quotes and concatenate the variable?

Comment: Ok, I see... Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I agree to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44806883/5213405) by [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin), but since you still have doubts, here is the explanation. Hope this helps.

- `'$val2'`

Variables and escape sequences for special characters will **not** be expanded(to the actual values they represent) when they occur in single quoted strings.
For Example -

```
// Outputs: This will not expand: \n a newline
echo 'This will not expand: \n a newline';

// Outputs: Variables do not $expand $either
echo 'Variables do not $expand $either';
```

So in your case, `'$val2'` will just add `$val2` string to the query, not its value.

- `\"$val3_escaped\"`

If the string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP **will interpret** all the variables and escape sequences for special characters. (ex - `\n`, `\t`, etc.).

`\"` - will just print the double-quote when used inside a double quote. :)
So in your case, PHP will get its actual value and add to the query (Due to the outer double quotes).

Example -

```
$juices = array("apple", "orange", "koolaid1" => "purple");
//Outputs : He drank some apple juice.
echo "He drank some $juices[0] juice."
```

You can refer to [PHP:Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) Manual for further details.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. So the right way should be \"$val3_escaped\", otherwise it cannot replace the var with its value. Now it's clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: Kindly mark it as an answer if it has helped you. Thanks :)

Comment: I've already upvoted your answer, but sorry, now I realize that the entire string is enclosed in double quotes, so the other answer is the most appropriate one. Thanks.